# How safe are Isolation Amplifiers compared to Voltage Transformer

Tags: amplifier, transformer, safety

I was searching for a miniature transformer for my 240V AC voltage measurement circuit and a kind individual recommended me a pecular IC. The IC is a [Differential Isolated Amplifier AMC1100](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/amc1100.pdf). And it checks everything i am looking for.

- Smaller Package than a transformer
- Cheaper than the transformer approach
- Can read (supposedly i still do not fully understand how it works) Mains voltage

This approach is new to me, contrary to what i know that transformer approach is the safest way to do this. Take a look at the diagram below. How safe is the "safe section" and the circuit down the line ? When both parts fails, which has a worse failure scenario between iso-amplifier and the transformer ? Is the exposed section really safe to haphazardly touch ?

[image]

Comment: This part provides "basic" insulation.  Take a look at the IS0224 (TI).  It provided "reinforced insulation".  You can Google the difference.

Comment: @JohnD the IC says `4250-VPK basic isolation` as to my [candidate transformer](https://www.hammfg.com/electronics/transformers/power/160-161.pdf) `High insulation - Hipot of 2,000V RMS.`  So the IC is better?

Comment: One disadvantage of the isolation amplifier approach is that it requires power supplies on both sides, and of course those two power supplies must be isolated from each other or you defeat the whole purpose. A transformer doesn't need anything on the mains side besides the mains itself.

Comment: Is the IC better? Maybe, maybe not.  Reinforced insulation is designed so that a fault in one of the barriers doesn't create an unsafe condition.  Your transformer may be designed that way, for example with triple-insulated wire.  The IC provides only basic insulation, meaning that you need to provide another safety barrier against shock (e.g. double insulation) if you want it to be as safe.  See here: http://download.ni.com/pub/gdc/tut/isolator_safety.pdf

Comment: @JohnD Of course safety step that can done on the PCB will be done, leaving the most common weakpoint is the IC itself internally. So Transformers are still superior to safety when it comes to safety

Comment: @Jakequin If you are considering this particular IC.  Other ICs provide reinforced insulation and can be considered as safe as a reinforced insulation transformer.

Comment: @JohnD oh no, not necessarily it was the IC that was recommended to me, as long as it performs what i need (AC mains voltage reading and is safe). Im still looking at the options. Are you still refering to isolation amplifiers or a totaly different type of IC? I would really like to know what those IC are.